# Passing Array via SOAP for SAP Webservice

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, soap

I am trying to pass a 2D Array via SOAP for SAP Webservice. 
But I am unable to pass the same.

I am able to pass a value, also I am able to accept a table output from SAP.
Please guide.

I tried to typecast array as an object.

My Code:

```
<?php       
    include("include/config.php");

    $sql = "SELECT tid,OrderNumber FROM transhistory ORDER by timestamp ASC limit 2";
    $result= mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        //Array based on output table
        $pmt[$i][0] = "";                       //Mandt
        $pmt[$i][1] = $row["tid"];              //Refnum
        $pmt[$i][2] = $row["OrderNumber"];  //Orderno

        $i++;
    }

    /*Two methods I tried */   
    $object = (object) $pmt;
    $object = json_decode(json_encode($pmt), FALSE);

    #Define Authentication 
    $SOAP_AUTH = array( 'login'    => 'abc',
                        'password' => 'abc');

    #Specify WSDL
    $WSDL = "working URL here";

    #Create Client Object, download and parse WSDL
    $client = new SoapClient($WSDL,$SOAP_AUTH);

    #Setup input parameters (SAP Likes to Capitalise the parameter names)
    $params = array(
          'Zpmt' => $object 
    );

    #Call Operation (Function). Catch and display any errors
    try {
        $result = $client->ZphpOT($params);
    } catch (SoapFault $exception) {
        echo 'Error!Server Connectivity issue. Please try again later.';
        die();
    }      
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the answer may be useful for somebody but usually you send parameters like this

```
$result = $client->ZphpOT("VARIABLE_NAME"=>$params);
```